# the difference in used hard drive space as shown by df and du is HUGE!

Tags: filesystems, disk-usage

It seems that du discounts the #open files when calculating the disk usage, and this hit me when I saw that df is showing 100% usage, while du says only 40% is in use.

when i looked up on this, i came to realize that there are some open files that are used by the active processes that take up space

```
sudo /usr/sbin/lsof | grep services
```

Output:

```
java       3772      root   44r      REG                9,5     76608   11649161 /services/apache-tomcat-6.0.20/lib/jsp-api.jar
java       3772      root   74r      REG                9,5    724225   16829492 /services/apache-tomcat-6.0.20/webapps/myapp/WEB-INF/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.10-bin.jar
smbd       3794      root  mem       REG                9,5      8192   12320776 /services/samba/etc/secrets.tdb
smbd       3794      root    2w      REG                9,5      1096   12320780 /services/samba/logs/smbd.log
```

the grand total of open files shown by this command (7th column in the output shown) is almost >60% of the total allotted 200GB space.

This is surprising to me that i can count on only 40% of my partition for actual storage. Really! is this normal.

I use this partition for hosting mysql database, tomcat server, samba, svn etc.

What are my options here? How can i tune this up to be able to use all 200GB for my data and not open files, if that is a normal expectation!

## Newly added information

as per some of your suggestions here is the output from `du`, `df` and `lsof`. the problem i want to resolve is not have too many open files which is unusually occupying more than 50% of the allotted disk space.

1. My /services partition is originally allotted 184GB space (as shown in `df` command)
2. But my `du` command shows only 67GB (649GB-582GB) is occupied (excluding /services/BackupDir which is external drive)
3. while my `lsof` shows that there is 205GB open files (grand total of column#7), which is absurd because 205GB + 67GB is > 184GB!

```
#df showing the hard drive and the external drive on /dev/sde
>df -h
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/md0               43G   21G   21G  50% /
/dev/md1              145M   37M  101M  27% /boot
tmpfs                 1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev/shm
/dev/md3              230G  168G   63G  73% /sharefolder1
/dev/md4              230G   51G  179G  23% /sharefolder2
/dev/md5              184G  183G  1.4G 100% /services
/dev/md6              138G   33G  106G  24% /home
/dev/md7               94G  3.5G   90G   4% /users
/dev/md8              230G  196G   23G  90% /sharefolder3
/dev/md9              230G  102G  116G  47% /sharefolder4
/dev/md10             459G  367G   69G  85% /sharefolder5
/dev/sde1             459G  141G  318G  31% /services/BackupDir/ext1
/dev/sde2             230G   85G  145G  37% /services/BackupDir/ext2
/dev/sde3             230G  102G  128G  45% /services/BackupDir/ext3
/dev/sde5             230G   47G  183G  21% /services/BackupDir/ext4
/dev/sde6             230G  172G   58G  75% /services/BackupDir/ext5
/dev/sde7             230G   38G  192G  17% /services/BackupDir/ext6
/dev/sde8             230G  188M  230G   1% /services/BackupDir/ext7

#du showing only /services partition on the hard drive the subfolder BackupDir is the mounted external hard drive
>sudo du --max-depth=1 -h /services
1.2G    /services/svn
331M    /services/httpd
582G    /services/BackupDir
16K     /services/lost+found
600M    /services/netbeans-6.8
55G     /services/apache-tomcat-6.0.20
9.3G    /services/apache-tomcat-5.5.25
365M    /services/mysql
3.7M    /services/samba
649G    /services

#lsof command on /services 
> sudo /usr/sbin/lsof | grep services
mysqld     3632     mysql  cwd       DIR                9,5      4096   15220739 /services/mysql/lib
mysqld     3632     mysql    1u      REG                9,5     51725   15220742 /services/mysql/log/mysqld.log
mysqld     3632     mysql    2u      REG                9,5     51725   15220742 /services/mysql/log/mysqld.log
mysqld     3632     mysql    3uW     REG                9,5 161480704   15220797 /services/mysql/lib/ibdata1
mysqld     3632     mysql    8uW     REG                9,5   5242880   15220798 /services/mysql/lib/ib_logfile0
mysqld     3632     mysql    9uW     REG                9,5   5242880   15220799 /services/mysql/lib/ib_logfile1
mysqld     3632     mysql   13u      REG                9,5      1024   15220750 /services/mysql/lib/mysql/host.MYI
mysqld     3632     mysql   14u      REG                9,5         0   15220751 /services/mysql/lib/mysql/host.MYD
mysqld     3632     mysql   15u      REG                9,5      2048   15220753 /services/mysql/lib/mysql/user.MYI
mysqld     3632     mysql   16u      REG                9,5      2032   15220754 /services/mysql/lib/mysql/user.MYD
mysqld     3632     mysql   17u      REG                9,5      4096   15220747 /services/mysql/lib/mysql/db.MYI
mysqld     3632     mysql   18u      REG                9,5     17520   15220748 /services/mysql/lib/mysql/db.MYD
mysqld     3632     mysql   19u      REG                9,5      5120   15220759 /services/mysql/lib/mysql/tables_priv.MYI
mysqld     3632     mysql   20u      REG                9,5      3404   15220760 /services/mysql/lib/mysql/tables_priv.MYD
mysqld     3632     mysql   21u      REG                9,5      1024   15220762 /services/mysql/lib/mysql/columns_priv.MYI
mysqld     3632     mysql   22u      REG                9,5         0   15220763 /services/mysql/lib/mysql/columns_priv.MYD
mysqld     3632     mysql   23u      REG                9,5      1024   15220795 /services/mysql/lib/mysql/procs_priv.MYI
mysqld     3632     mysql   24u      REG                9,5         0   15220796 /services/mysql/lib/mysql/procs_priv.MYD
mysqld     3632     mysql   26u      REG                9,5      3072   15220792 /services/mysql/lib/mysql/proc.MYI
mysqld     3632     mysql   27u      REG                9,5      1852   15220793 /services/mysql/lib/mysql/proc.MYD
smbd       3752      root  mem       REG                9,5      8192   12320776 /services/samba/etc/secrets.tdb
smbd       3752      root    2w      REG                9,5      1096   12320780 /services/samba/logs/smbd.log
smbd       3752      root    7u      REG                9,5      8192   12320776 /services/samba/etc/secrets.tdb
smbd       3752      root   24w      REG                9,5      1096   12320780 /services/samba/logs/smbd.log
nmbd       3755      root    2w      REG                9,5      2028   12320784 /services/samba/logs/nmbd.log
nmbd       3755      root    3w      REG                9,5      2028   12320784 /services/samba/logs/nmbd.log
java       3772      root  mem       REG                9,5     17508   11649135 /services/apache-tomcat-6.0.20/bin/bootstrap.jar
java       3772      root  mem       REG                9,5      9341   11649138 /services/apache-tomcat-6.0.20/bin/commons-daemon.jar
java       3772      root  mem       REG                9,5     19399   11649146 /services/apache-tomcat-6.0.20/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
java       3772      root  mem       REG                9,5    795412   11649645 /services/apache-tomcat-6.0.20/lib/poi-scratchpad-3.5-FINAL-20090928.jar
java       3772      root  mem       REG                9,5    383040   11649637 /services/apache-tomcat-6.0.20/lib/commons-io-1.3.2-javadoc.jar
java       3772      root  mem       REG                9,5   1516415   11649642 /services/apache-tomcat-6.0.20/lib/poi-3.5-FINAL-20090928.jar
java       3772      root  mem       REG                9,5   1395266   11649159 /services/apache-tomcat-6.0.20/lib/jasper-jdt.jar
java       3772      root  mem       REG                9,5    103201   11649158 /services/apache-tomcat-6.0.20/lib/jasper-el.jar
java       3772      root  mem       REG                9,5    123820   11649154 /services/apache-tomcat-6.0.20/lib/catalina-ha.jar
java       3772      root  mem       REG                9,5     88209   11649162 /services/apache-tomcat-6.0.20/lib/servlet-api.jar
java       3772      root  mem       REG                9,5    724225   11650061 /services/apache-tomcat-6.0.20/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.10-bin.jar
java       3772      root  mem       REG                9,5   1146570   11649156 /services/apache-tomcat-6.0.20/lib/catalina.jar
java       3772      root  mem       REG                9,5    163177   11649641 /services/apache-tomcat-6.0.20/lib/commons-io-1.4-sources.jar
java       3772      root  mem       REG                9,5    109043   11649639 /services/apache-tomcat-6.0.20/lib/commons-io-1.4.jar
java       3772      root  mem       REG                9,5    197445   11649164 /services/apache-tomcat-6.0.20/lib/tomcat-dbcp.jar
java       3772      root  mem       REG                9,5     69040   11649643 /services/apache-tomcat-6.0.20/lib/poi-contrib-3.5-FINAL-20090928.jar
java       3772      root  mem       REG                9,5     27814   11649157 /services/apache-tomcat-6.0.20/lib/el-api.jar
java       3772      root  mem       REG                9,5    391250   11649644 /services/apache-tomcat-6.0.20/lib/poi-ooxml-3.5-FINAL-20090928.jar
java       3772      root  mem       REG                9,5    230149   11649155 /services/apache-tomcat-6.0.20/lib/catalina-tribes.jar
java       3772      root  mem       REG                9,5    275779   11649634 /services/apache-tomcat-6.0.20/lib/commons-fileupload-1.2.1-javadoc.jar
java       3772      root  mem       REG                9,5    513722   11649160 /services/apache-tomcat-6.0.20/lib/jasper.jar
java       3772      root  mem       REG                9,5     87776   11649636 /services/apache-tomcat-6.0.20/lib/commons-io-1.3.2.jar
java       3772      root  mem       REG                9,5    135544   11649638 /services/apache-tomcat-6.0.20/lib/commons-io-1.3.2-sources.jar
java       3772      root  mem       REG                9,5     66144   11649165 /services/apache-tomcat-6.0.20/lib/tomcat-i18n-es.jar
java       3772      root  mem       REG                9,5    499643   11649640 /services/apache-tomcat-6.0.20/lib/commons-io-1.4-javadoc.jar
java       3772      root  mem       REG                9,5     49147   11649153 /services/apache-tomcat-6.0.20/lib/catalina-ant.jar
java       3772      root  mem       REG                9,5     43742   11649166 /services/apache-tomcat-6.0.20/lib/tomcat-i18n-fr.jar
java       3772      root  mem       REG                9,5     57779   11649632 /services/apache-tomcat-6.0.20/lib/commons-fileupload-1.2.1.jar
java       3772      root  mem       REG                9,5     10807   11649152 /services/apache-tomcat-6.0.20/lib/annotations-api.jar
java       3772      root  mem       REG                9,5    750470   11649163 /services/apache-tomcat-6.0.20/lib/tomcat-coyote.jar
java       3772      root  mem       REG                9,5     73721   11649635 /services/apache-tomcat-6.0.20/lib/commons-fileupload-1.2.1-sources.jar
java       3772      root  mem       REG                9,5     49021   11649167 /services/apache-tomcat-6.0.20/lib/tomcat-i18n-ja.jar
java       3772      root  mem       REG                9,5     76608   11649161 /services/apache-tomcat-6.0.20/lib/jsp-api.jar
java       3772      root  mem       REG                9,5    724225   16829492 /services/apache-tomcat-6.0.20/webapps/myapp/WEB-INF/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.10-bin.jar
java       3772      root    1w      REG                9,5     79186    9404433 /services/apache-tomcat-6.0.20/logs/catalina.out
java       3772      root    2w      REG                9,5     79186    9404433 /services/apache-tomcat-6.0.20/logs/catalina.out
java       3772      root    5r      REG                9,5     17508   11649135 /services/apache-tomcat-6.0.20/bin/bootstrap.jar
java       3772      root    9r      REG                9,5      9341   11649138 /services/apache-tomcat-6.0.20/bin/commons-daemon.jar
java       3772      root   10r      REG                9,5     19399   11649146 /services/apache-tomcat-6.0.20/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
java       3772      root   11w      REG                9,5     32125    9404434 /services/apache-tomcat-6.0.20/logs/catalina.2013-09-18.log
java       3772      root   12w      REG                9,5     24718    9404435 /services/apache-tomcat-6.0.20/logs/localhost.2013-09-18.log
java       3772      root   13w      REG                9,5      5336    9404436 /services/apache-tomcat-6.0.20/logs/manager.2013-09-18.log
java       3772      root   14w      REG                9,5         0    9404437 /services/apache-tomcat-6.0.20/logs/host-manager.2013-09-18.log
java       3772      root   15r      REG                9,5    795412   11649645 /services/apache-tomcat-6.0.20/lib/poi-scratchpad-3.5-FINAL-20090928.jar
java       3772      root   16r      REG                9,5    383040   11649637 /services/apache-tomcat-6.0.20/lib/commons-io-1.3.2-javadoc.jar
java       3772      root   17r      REG                9,5   1516415   11649642 /services/apache-tomcat-6.0.20/lib/poi-3.5-FINAL-20090928.jar
java       3772      root   18r      REG                9,5   1395266   11649159 /services/apache-tomcat-6.0.20/lib/jasper-jdt.jar
java       3772      root   19r      REG                9,5    103201   11649158 /services/apache-tomcat-6.0.20/lib/jasper-el.jar
java       3772      root   20r      REG                9,5    123820   11649154 /services/apache-tomcat-6.0.20/lib/catalina-ha.jar
java       3772      root   21r      REG                9,5     88209   11649162 /services/apache-tomcat-6.0.20/lib/servlet-api.jar
java       3772      root   22r      REG                9,5    724225   11650061 /services/apache-tomcat-6.0.20/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.10-bin.jar
java       3772      root   23r      REG                9,5   1146570   11649156 /services/apache-tomcat-6.0.20/lib/catalina.jar
java       3772      root   24r      REG                9,5    163177   11649641 /services/apache-tomcat-6.0.20/lib/commons-io-1.4-sources.jar
java       3772      root   25r      REG                9,5    109043   11649639 /services/apache-tomcat-6.0.20/lib/commons-io-1.4.jar
java       3772      root   26r      REG                9,5    197445   11649164 /services/apache-tomcat-6.0.20/lib/tomcat-dbcp.jar
java       3772      root   27r      REG                9,5     69040   11649643 /services/apache-tomcat-6.0.20/lib/poi-contrib-3.5-FINAL-20090928.jar
java       3772      root   28r      REG                9,5     27814   11649157 /services/apache-tomcat-6.0.20/lib/el-api.jar
java       3772      root   29r      REG                9,5    391250   11649644 /services/apache-tomcat-6.0.20/lib/poi-ooxml-3.5-FINAL-20090928.jar
java       3772      root   30r      REG                9,5    230149   11649155 /services/apache-tomcat-6.0.20/lib/catalina-tribes.jar
java       3772      root   31r      REG                9,5    275779   11649634 /services/apache-tomcat-6.0.20/lib/commons-fileupload-1.2.1-javadoc.jar
java       3772      root   32r      REG                9,5    513722   11649160 /services/apache-tomcat-6.0.20/lib/jasper.jar
java       3772      root   33r      REG                9,5     87776   11649636 /services/apache-tomcat-6.0.20/lib/commons-io-1.3.2.jar
java       3772      root   34r      REG                9,5    135544   11649638 /services/apache-tomcat-6.0.20/lib/commons-io-1.3.2-sources.jar
java       3772      root   35r      REG                9,5     66144   11649165 /services/apache-tomcat-6.0.20/lib/tomcat-i18n-es.jar
java       3772      root   36r      REG                9,5    499643   11649640 /services/apache-tomcat-6.0.20/lib/commons-io-1.4-javadoc.jar
java       3772      root   37r      REG                9,5     49147   11649153 /services/apache-tomcat-6.0.20/lib/catalina-ant.jar
java       3772      root   38r      REG                9,5     43742   11649166 /services/apache-tomcat-6.0.20/lib/tomcat-i18n-fr.jar
java       3772      root   39r      REG                9,5     57779   11649632 /services/apache-tomcat-6.0.20/lib/commons-fileupload-1.2.1.jar
java       3772      root   40r      REG                9,5     10807   11649152 /services/apache-tomcat-6.0.20/lib/annotations-api.jar
java       3772      root   41r      REG                9,5    750470   11649163 /services/apache-tomcat-6.0.20/lib/tomcat-coyote.jar
java       3772      root   42r      REG                9,5     73721   11649635 /services/apache-tomcat-6.0.20/lib/commons-fileupload-1.2.1-sources.jar
java       3772      root   43r      REG                9,5     49021   11649167 /services/apache-tomcat-6.0.20/lib/tomcat-i18n-ja.jar
java       3772      root   44r      REG                9,5     76608   11649161 /services/apache-tomcat-6.0.20/lib/jsp-api.jar
java       3772      root   74r      REG                9,5    724225   16829492 /services/apache-tomcat-6.0.20/webapps/myapp/WEB-INF/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.10-bin.jar
smbd       3794      root  mem       REG                9,5      8192   12320776 /services/samba/etc/secrets.tdb
smbd       3794      root    2w      REG                9,5      1096   12320780 /services/samba/logs/smbd.log
smbd       3794      root    5w      REG                9,5      1096   12320780 /services/samba/logs/smbd.log
smbd       3794      root    7u      REG                9,5      8192   12320776 /services/samba/etc/secrets.tdb
bash      10449  user1  cwd       DIR                9,5      4096   14516225 /services/BackupDir
smbd      10647      root  mem       REG                9,5      8192   12320776 /services/samba/etc/secrets.tdb
smbd      10647      root    2w      REG                9,5     50351   12320785 /services/samba/logs/sridevi-pc.log
smbd      10647      root    7u      REG                9,5      8192   12320776 /services/samba/etc/secrets.tdb
smbd      10647      root   27w      REG                9,5     50351   12320785 /services/samba/logs/sridevi-pc.log
rsync     11030  user1    3r      REG               9,10  21418176   23955858 /internalfile500GB/BackupDir/fileserver_services_bkup/internalfile-root-bkup/services/services/BackupDir/internalfile_repository_bkup/cng_repository/Deepak/DissertationDefense/Dissertation/Expression/Expression Encoder/Screen Capture Output/ScreenCapture_7-25-2011 4.55.33 PM.xesc
smbd      11267      root  mem       REG                9,5      8192   12320776 /services/samba/etc/secrets.tdb
smbd      11267      root    2w      REG                9,5      6298   12321110 /services/samba/logs/drwindows8.log
smbd      11267      root    7u      REG                9,5      8192   12320776 /services/samba/etc/secrets.tdb
smbd      11267      root   28w      REG                9,5      6298   12321110 /services/samba/logs/drwindows8.log
smbd      11334      root  mem       REG                9,5      8192   12320776 /services/samba/etc/secrets.tdb
smbd      11334      root    2w      REG                9,5      5918   12321012 /services/samba/logs/nmo-dataprocess.log
smbd      11334      root    7u      REG                9,5      8192   12320776 /services/samba/etc/secrets.tdb
smbd      11334      root   32w      REG                9,5      5918   12321012 /services/samba/logs/nmo-dataprocess.log
smbd      11489      root  mem       REG                9,5      8192   12320776 /services/samba/etc/secrets.tdb
smbd      11489      root    2w      REG                9,5      3484   12320915 /services/samba/logs/hippocampus-pc.log
smbd      11489      root    7u      REG                9,5      8192   12320776 /services/samba/etc/secrets.tdb
smbd      11489      root   28w      REG                9,5      3484   12320915 /services/samba/logs/hippocampus-pc.log
sudo      11525      root  cwd       DIR                9,5      4096   14516225 /services/BackupDir
grep      11526  user1  cwd       DIR                9,5      4096   14516225 /services/BackupDir
lsof      11527      root  cwd       DIR                9,5      4096   14516225 /services/BackupDir
lsof      11528      root  cwd       DIR                9,5      4096   14516225 /services/BackupDir

#the size of deleted files in column#7 is 0 bytes!
> sudo /usr/sbin/lsof | grep deleted
mysqld     3632     mysql    4u      REG                9,0         0    7070979 /tmp/ibjpoC3F (deleted)
mysqld     3632     mysql    5u      REG                9,0         0    7070980 /tmp/ibTKRzCQ (deleted)
mysqld     3632     mysql    6u      REG                9,0         0    7070981 /tmp/ibvuExb1 (deleted)
mysqld     3632     mysql    7u      REG                9,0         0    7070983 /tmp/ibYLMOLb (deleted)
mysqld     3632     mysql   11u      REG                9,0         0    7070984 /tmp/ibQfuW1m (deleted)
gpm        3690      root    0u      CHR              136,0       0t0          2 /dev/pts/0 (deleted)
gpm        3690      root    1u      CHR              136,0       0t0          2 /dev/pts/0 (deleted)
gpm        3690      root    2u      CHR              136,0       0t0          2 /dev/pts/0 (deleted)
```

Comment: how do i respond to comments using full fromatting capabilities that i used to post my question?

Comment: I always use `du -sh --apparent-size` too when running `du`. Just an FYI.

Comment: Thanks, but `du --appartent-size /services` is showing the same size as grand total of df available size for all the partitions.

Comment: but i can't make sense of what's going on here! look the used size (column 3) is more than the available size (column 4): `/dev/md5             192251868 190878620   1373248 100% /services`

Comment: also, i have noticed another strange thing in `lsof` output. all log files are opened twice e.g., smbd.log, catalina.log, mysqld.log, etc.

Comment: The data `du` is missing could be shadowed by a mount, or kept in snapshots (if btrfs).  Unlinked files is just one possibility.

Comment: Can you please be more specific. I don't understand what do you mean by du is missing! Is there a command that you would suggest to check for unlinked files?

Comment: What are you talking about?  You haven't shown the output of `du` or `df` and the `lsof` output you did show only covers a bit over 750k.  `du` does not miss open files unless they are also deleted.

Comment: yes, i have posted only partial info. Can you please tell what's the best way to post my output to this thread, they are big and the comment can take only few lines...

Comment: @user2105887 You use the "edit" link below your post to edit the requested material into your question.

Comment: The total size of files in the `lsof` output is 205 MB, not GB.  To have `du` not count files in the other mount points, use the -x switch, as in `du -s -x /services`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that you've misread the output of the commands you ran several times.

> the grand total of open files shown by this command (7th column in the output shown) is almost >60% of the total allotted 200GB space.

I have no idea where you got that figure. The total for the lines you show is about 800kB, which is about 0.0004% of 200GB.

If you added more lines than shown here, keep in mind that:

- If a file was opened by multiple processes, or even on multiple descriptors by the same process (it happens), you've counted it multiple times.
- Some of these files are on different filesystems.

> How can i tune this up to be able to use all 200GB for my data and not open files, if that is a normal expectation!

There is nothing to tune up. You can use all your space. You're just making bizarre interpretations of the output of the commands you ran to measure disk usage.

> ```
> sudo du --max-depth=1 -h /services
> ```

There are mount points under `/services`, so this sums up the size of files that are not on the `/services` filesystem but on `/services/BackupDir/ext1` and its siblings.

The output from this command doesn't provide much useful information about the disk usage on `/services`. Pass the option `-x` to `du` to tell it not to descend into mount points.

```
sudo du -x -h /services
```

If the size reported by *this* command is less than the “occupied” size reported by `df /services`, there are two possible causes:

- You have some files that are deleted but still open. These files still take up space, but they have no name so `du` won't find them. They would show up in the output of `lsof`. Run `lsof +F1 /services` to see a list of deleted but open files on `/services`.
- There are files hidden behind some of the mount points under `/services`. Maybe one of your applications ran while these filesystems wasn't mounted as expected and therefore wrote files on the parent filesystem. When a filesystem is mounted on a directory, this hides the files in that directory, but of course the files are still there. Run the following commands to create an alternate view of `/services` without the lower mount points and explore that.

  ```
  mkdir /root/services-view
  mount --bind /services /root/services-view
  du /root/services-view/BackupDir/ext?
  ```

Comment: i can't believe it! like you said it is the mount point that was not created properly and the backup was written onto the disk. the df, du and lsof confused the whole thing. df is showing the size in KB, and i went with the same assumption with lsof, which was showing in bytes.

Answer (score 5):

Having this discrepancy between `du` and `df` isn't uncommon, but having this large a discrepancy is - in my experience - very unusual. This type of discrepancy happens, in my experience, when an application file (usually a log file) is removed via `rm`, but is still open in the application, so the filehandle remains open and the kernel won't permit deletion of the actual data, but the inode entry in the directory is removed. Thus, `df` shows the space is still taken, but `du` which looks at an enumeration of files in a directory, doesn't see that file and shows that space available. The best suggestion I can give you is to work with the applications to try to reduce the number of filehandles they keep open.

Comment: Thanks John, what you are suggesting seems very reasonable, but i don't see that here.

Comment: I tired this: sudo /usr/sbin/lsof |grep "deleted" and there are bunch of mysql files that are marked as deleted but they are 0bytes.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to already suggested causes, it could be also following:

- **a different disk is mounted "over" the existing folder which is full of data**
- du will calculate the size spent of mounted disk and df will show really spent
- solution: (when possible) unmount all non-root disks and check the size with `du -md 1` again. Fix situation by moving *hidden* folder to some other place or mount on different place.